# What is the purpose of `Array#reject!` returning `nil` when there are no changes?

Tags: ruby, arrays

`Array#reject!` returns `nil` in case the block evaluates to `false` for every element in the receiver (which is altered in place, and in this case does not change), in comparison to `Array#reject`:

```
a=1,2,3
a.reject {false} # => [1, 2, 3]
a.reject! {false} # => nil
```

This seems to me rather weird. Why has `Array#reject!` been designed to do so? Should `Array#reject!` behave like `Array#reject` in this case?

I would like to be able to chain methods like `select!`, `reject!` and `map!`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: _Equivalent to #delete_if, deleting elements from self for which the block evaluates to true, but returns nil if no changes were made._

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Of course it does, I am not asking **if it does**, I am asking **why**

Comment: @DhruvaSagar Because it was designed that way. Trying to guess/justify rational is generally Not Constructive. Perhaps there is an old article on the ML that discusses the *design choice*. In any case, it's not "broken".

Comment: Though, I can say that because it works this way you now have a way to check to see if it is changed or not.  If it is a 'truthy' return, then it was successfully changed in the case of reject!.  If it is nil, then nothing was rejected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `delete_if` instead? The rest of the stuff chains well.

---

`reject` works like `select`, it's actually returning a new container, and then just points to the new one because you ask for !, whereas, `delete_if` is doing that in place, directly.

I agree that it isn't natural, but what can happen a lot, is you write:

```
value = a.reject!; if value, do {something} end
```

So it sort of makes sense that it returns null, because presumably if there were no rejections, nothing needs to be done. If you were expecting something to change, then you would just use `select!`.

Comment: Thanks @Kasumi, you should consider adding your comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think `reject!` was designed to return nil when no changes are made so it could be used nicely like this:

```
candidates.reject! { |c| ... } or puts "Unable to reject any candidates."
```

Since `reject!` returns nil when there are no rejections, the part after the "or" is only run if there are no rejections.

You could also do something like Kasumi's answer.